# Removendo campos de uma list

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Estou com uma dúvida. Criei uma list e queria remover os elementos dela clicando no 'x' como na imagem a seguir (Coloquei o x pelo paint):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer desta maneira? É um atributo ou é configurável por outra linguagem??
Perdão a ignorância

```html
<input list="sel-opts" id="new-opt" />
<datalist id="sel-opts">
 <option>#</option>
    <option>@</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Qual é o HTML/JavaScript dessa lista?

Comment: Vou editar com o código, um momento

Comment: Coloquei um código básico de uma lista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai utilizar jQuery ou javascript pra isso, podendo também ser feito apenas com CSS.

Vou dar um resposta com jQuery, basta adicionar um evento `'click'` ao botão de remover, e remover o elemento li mais próximo buscado com `'closest'`, no caso utilizei o método `hide()`, mas também existem outros métodos.

Segue exemplo funcional:

```js
$(document).on('click','.remover',function(){
   $(this).closest('li').hide();
});

$(document).on('click','.mostrar',function(){
   $(this).closest('ul').find('li').show();
});
```

```css
.remover {
text-decoration: none;
float:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
  coisa 1 <a href="#" class="remover fa fa-minus"> </a>
  </li>
  <li>
  coisa 2 <a href="#" class="remover fa fa-minus"> </a>
  </li>
  <li>
  coisa 3 <a href="#" class="remover fa fa-minus"> </a>
  </li>
  <li>
  coisa 4 <a href="#" class="remover fa fa-minus"> </a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="#" class="mostrar"> (Mostrar tudo)</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

PS: Existem diversas respostas que responderiam essa pergunta, na minha opinião jQuery facilita a vida.

Comment: Ótima ideia !! vou tentar algo aqui com base no que tenho, só um momento

Comment: Se não conseguir coloca o html da lista junto na pergunta ali

Comment: Eu coloquei o do datalist, a princípio preciso remover os itens do datalist

Comment: Você ta usando esse plugin http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/ ?

Comment: Não, até então estou querendo só excluir itens já predeterminados

Comment: Você consegue inspecionar o elemento do 'x' né ? pega algum classname dele, coloca no evento click, e dispara isso dentro do evento '$('elemento x').closest('option').remove()' , quase a mesma coisa do exemplo, só muda os elementos apontados

Comment: Pults esqueci de explicar

Comment: Aquele x coloquei pelo paint, não consegui nem coloca-lo ali

Comment: Ata, então me responda algumas coisas. isso é um autocomplete ? Está usando algum framework CSS ? Existem alguma biblioteca externa alem do jQuery ? pra eu saber qual seria a melhor resposta.

Comment: Não não, somente imagens redirecionadas sem funções, o código principal eu editei na pergunta que é o data list, preciso remover os itens já adicionados pelo `<option>#</option>`

Comment: Da uma olhada na resposta agr, se for isso eu arrumo explicando

Comment: Perfeito !! já ajuda muito, obrigado @AnthraxisBR, vou estudar o código, qualquer coisa pergunto ok??

Comment: Nice, só mais uma dica, de uma olhada em frameworks CSS em vez de fazer coisas com imagens que acabam pesando muito, recomendo Bootstrap CSS, facilita muito pra criar templates e poupa trabalho.

Comment: Beleza!! valeu :D